# Responsive equal height divs on click

Tags: jquery

I have two divs where I have applied equal height jQuery and it works fine during resize too. But I have an accordion slider in left content, when I click the tab head in left content, the content displays and left content height increase and right content height is not adjusted too it.

Please someone help me with this. Here is the jQuery code I have used :

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) 
{
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(
        function() 
        {
            currentHeight = $(this).height();
            if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) 
            {
                tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
            }
        }
    );
    columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setEqualHeight($(".eqgroup > .eqheight"));
});
window.onresize = OnResizeDocument;
function OnResizeDocument () {
    $(".eqgroup > .eqheight").css('height', 'auto')
    setEqualHeight($(".eqgroup > .eqheight"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happeneing now is that the script is called only on resize.

You must call the script, not only on resize but also when the accordion expands an item (usually on click i guess)

The code you must call is this:

```
$(".eqgroup > .eqheight").css('height', 'auto')
setEqualHeight($(".eqgroup > .eqheight"));
```

It is the same as what is called in the `onResize` event.